# C programming manually increment signal handler's PC

Tags: c, signals

I am new to C programming and run into a problem when doing an exercise to increment the PC of a segmentation fault signal handler using only flag's address. By referencing the flag signum, I already got the address of the flag within the code's stack , but how do I know by how much should I increment it to the where the PC stored instruction pointer to advance the program counter manually?

```
void segf_handler(int signum)
{
int address=&signum;

}
int main()
{
int n = 0;

signal(SIGSEGV, segment_fault_handler);

n = *( (int *) 0 );

printf("recover from segfault\n");

return 0;
}
```

Thank You!

Comment: Do you mean you want to discover the function's return address?  Because the PC is stored in a register; it has no address, and all you need to do to increment it is to evaluate substantially any expression.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I meant to increment the pointer to where the program counter is stored to advance PC manually so that when the handler return, the code will run after the instruction that caused segfault

Comment: Because instructions have variable length, it is not posible to "advance" the PC to any next instruction: you don't know how many bytes to skip (unless you analyze the instruction(s)).

Comment: @PaulOgilvie It's just a exercise for better understanding. I will be able to find the length of instruction this particular machine by viewing the assembly code. But my problem is to find the instruction pointer or PC to advance the pc manually

Comment: Then you must inspect the call frame (assembler) the compiler generates for a function call. It will tell you how many bytes to add or subtract from the (first) parameter's address. That number of bytes will always be the same (depending on platform and compiler).

Comment: Again, @ghosttang, the PC is stored *in a register*.  Registers are part of the CPU, not of system memory.  Therefore they have no addresses, and you cannot obtain a pointer to one in any way.  Moreover, when you're executing the code of the signal handler, the PC has already changed from the location of the instruction that caused the segfault.  That's why I asked whether you meant the *return address*, which would be a valid value for the PC to take.

Comment: Note further that the machine may have invoked first its own segfault handler, which calls the user segfault handler. There is no guarantee you find the address of the faulting instruction.

Comment: (On the other hand, if a debugger can put me at the place of a faulting instruction, then it must be possible to get its address...)

Comment: In fact, if you want the program to resume where it was after a segfault, then it is likely that all you need to do is set the disposition for `SIGSEGV` to `SIG_IGN`, or, alternatively, to install a signal handler that returns without terminating the program.  Signal handling is *asynchronous*: resuming where the main code left off is standard behavior.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Sorry I think I understood how the program counter works wrong. The purpose of this exercise is to recover from segfult and keep the codes alive by advance PC pass the offending instruction. If the PC will read from the return address, does it mean that I only need to increment the value in the return address by the length of bad instruction to have the PC advance?

Comment: @ghosttang, your focus on the PC or even on a return address is probably misplaced.  C does not define any mechanism for manipulating these; they are not even part of the abstract machine model that serves as the basis for the language specifications.  If you're looking for a ***C*** solution for recovering from a segfault, then see my comments about signal disposition and signal handler implementation.

Comment: @JohnBollinger You're badly mistaken - just for starters, setting `SIGSEGV` to `SIG_IGN` and then doing anything that would trigger delivery of `SIGSEGV` provokes undefined behavior; same for returning normally from a SIGSEGV handler without having taken any action to clear the fault (in the latter case, the most likely outcome is an infinite loop between the faulting instruction and the handler).  It's true that the functionality OP is asking for is not included in the C standard, but it is possible using POSIX + one piece of completely unportable code - see my answer.

Comment: @zwol, I accept that my suggestion might not work, but program behavior is *already* undefined (by C) when the program performs an action that results in a segfault being raised, other than calling `raise()`.  From there on, we're in Wonderland.  Moreover, modifying the `mcontext_t` obtained from a `ucontext_t`, as you suggest, itself necessarily exhibits undefined (by C or POSIX) behavior.  That's more or less equivalent to your description of it as "completely unportable".

Answer (score 1):

In order to gain access to the location of the saved PC, you must use [`sigaction`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaction) and a three-argument signal handler:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <ucontext.h>

void segf_handler(int sig, siginfo_t *info, void *cx_)
{
    ucontext_t *cx = cx_;

    /* Extremely OS- and architecture-specific manipulation
       of the data pointed to by `cx` goes here */
}

int *volatile cause_crash = 0;

int main(void)
{
    struct sigaction sa;
    sigfillset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_sigaction = segf_handler;
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART | SA_SIGINFO;
    if (sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, 0)) {
        perror("sigaction");
        return 1;
    }
    *cause_crash = 0;
    puts("recovered from segfault");
    return 0;
}
```

The saved PC will be *somewhere* within the data pointed to by `cx`, and you can manipulate it to change where normal control will resume.  The data pointed to by `info` will also include useful details for programs trying to do this sort of thing, such as (for SIGSEGV) the bad address that the faulting instruction tried to access.

Unfortunately, I can't tell you where to find the PC, because the contents of a `ucontext_t` are not standardized *at all*, and vary radically with both the CPU and the operating system, and you have not told us either one.

Note that `sigaction` is not part of any version of the C standard.  Everything used by the above code, except for the contents of `ucontext_t`, is part of POSIX.1-1996, so you can count on its working on anything you're likely to be using *except* for certain embedded operating systems and Windows.  In particular, on Windows you need to do something *completely different* that I don't understand well enough to describe.

Note also that if your instructor told you it was possible to access the saved PC using `signal` and/or a one-argument signal handler, then they were wrong, and if they *required* you to do that as part of an exercise, then that is an improper requirement, and in both cases you may tell them I said so.

Comment: since the exercise is only limited to specific machine, is it possible to find the address where PC stored using debugger or read through assembly code?

Comment: @ghosttang What you should do is read through `ucontext.h` and the headers it includes.  If you still have no clue, ask a new question specifically about the contents of `ucontext_t` on your CPU and OS, and you'll have to tell us which ones they are.